# Misty - Rupert Austin Fingering

Tags: piano, jazz

[image]

I'm taking on the task of learning this piece and I'm not too familiar with jazz chords or fingerings. Can someone help with the following passage, or at least give tips on how to figure out proper fingering? Thanks!

Comment: For the first box, I tried 24121 241(23)4 but didn't like the crossing of the thumb to reach the C. The second one, I didn't know when to cross the thumb to reach the Db, and the third and fourth, nothing worked well, so I have no ideas for it.

Comment: Actually, there is a video showing someone playing this exact arrangement: https://youtu.be/XiFWcHJ2ixA?t=97 perhaps it's helpful?

Comment: Just don't ask Clint Eastwood to play it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first, try 21231231 and play the grace notes+next note with 234.

For the second, try 123454543. This one is debatable, only if you have good ability to cross 4 and 5.

The third has many possible fingerings, and neither is "better" than the other. I'd suggest starting with 1234, and your strengths in crossings will dictate the rest.

For the fourth, 23 12345432143214321432 is probably the most comfortable.

All fingerings are based on your finger crossing strengths and weaknesses. Feel free to change this around a bit.